# Can MySQL JSON columns be indexed in version 8.0.19?

Tags: mysql, json, indexing

According to this webpage, MySQL JSON columns cannot be indexed.

[MySQL Server Blog](https://mysqlserverteam.com/indexing-json-documents-via-virtual-columns/)

"JSON columns cannot be indexed. You can work around this restriction by creating an index on a generated column that extracts a scalar value from the JSON column."

Can someone please tell me if this is changed in latest MySQL community version 8.0.19?

What will give me the best performance? A index on a generated column or a duplicate (a non JSON column with the exact same text as in the JSON column) column with normal fulltext search?

Comment: Simpler with a "generated column".  `FULLTEXT` is better when "prose" is being searched for "words".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is still the case, from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html):

> JSON columns, like columns of other binary types, are not indexed
>   directly; instead, you can create an index on a generated column that
>   extracts a scalar value from the JSON column. See Indexing a Generated
>   Column to Provide a JSON Column Index, for a detailed example.

and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html) also:

> **Indexing a Generated Column to Provide a JSON Column Index**
>   As noted elsewhere, JSON columns cannot be indexed directly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: "Multi-valued" indexing is also available for json arrays.  Study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued  (Note: 8.0.17)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a handy way to store somewhat arbitrary information in a database table.  If will regularly use the *components* of the JSON in RDBMS operations, such as indexing, then you should pull them out of the JSON (or copy them out).